# iphone load csv into UITable

Tags: iphone, uitableview, csv

I wish make this thing: load an csv took from the web (http://mywebsite.com/myfile.csv) and parse into a UITableView...
is there any fast method to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSV parser with low memory footprint for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031181/csv-parser-with-low-memory-footprint-for-iphone)