# The easiest way to convert an excel file in to a file readable by the iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have a excel sheet of some 3000 enteries. I want an easy way by which I can convert this file in to a file format which is readable by my iphone application and it automatically populates the data in that excel sheet in the rows of the table format in iphone app.

I am making an application which takes enteries from users and saves them in database.
The enteries displayed on the application which user would select and save in database , I want them to be populated through that excel sheet .

Please let me know what can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered CSV (comma separated values) file format? It is relatively easy to parse. It doesn't have some of the powerful aspects of Excel (e.g., no macros, etc.) but if it's just the raw data that you are concerned with, then that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Why didn't wetsider put his/her answer as an answer instead of a comment?*

Use CSV instead of the native Excel format. You can fairly simply parse CSV (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031181/csv-parser-with-low-memory-footprint-for-iphone)